# Format issue while uploading the file on S3 using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, axios

From third party api i am getting this type of data

````
%PDF-1.7 %���� 2093 0 obj <> endobj 2240 0 obj <>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[(\204\240\33\17\372\324FC\221_B\326\226\7\374\206) (\204\240\33\17\372\324FC\221_B\326\226\7\374\206)]/Index[2093 148]/Info 2092 0 R/Length 164/Prev 1150275/Root 2094 0 R/Size 2241/Type/XRef/W[1 3 1]>> stream x�cbd```b`` �� ���d4�6`�D2��`�L.��������`R���LZ�E������S�`"�V!،�`v���dbgc����0�`?ƃH��`�<0�DJ�lg|2�q��?u�^�Qr������w�|&�g&��ŕ��� endstream endobj startxref 0 %%EOF 2094 0 obj <>/Metadata 1312 0 R/Pages 1566 0 R/StructTreeRoot 1569 0 R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences 2140 0 R>> endobj 2238 0 obj <> stream
````

that is a pdf file that i want to upload on s3 and here is the code

```
const response = await axios.get(url, options);
const file = { originalname: `${docName}.pdf`, buffer: response.data };
await this.s3Service.upload(file, `${S3_BASE_PATH.DOCS}/ENQ_${enquiryDocDto.enquiryId}`);
```

and upload method on s3 service

```
async upload(file, basePath: string): Promise<string> {

    const fileName = this._getRandomFileName(file)
    const bucketFileKey = `${basePath}/${fileName}`;

    const params: AWS.S3.PutObjectRequest = {
      Bucket: this.bucketName,
      Key: bucketFileKey,
      Body: file.buffer
    };

    this.logger.log(`Uploading ${bucketFileKey}`);

    await this.s3.putObject(params).promise();
    this.logger.log(`Uploaded ${bucketFileKey}`);
    return bucketFileKey;
  }
```

from the api where i am getting this pdf data works on postman, and same data it returns and on saving the response from postman it creates a valid pdf.

but via code it is not uploading correctly

I have tried even creating the buffer like this

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, "utf-8")
```

even tried `"binary"` type but no luck.

the same upload s3 method works when i upload directly from my nodejs in that case `Buffer` comes

so i tried conervting it into `Buffer` but conversion shows it as `Uint8Array`

**UPdate1**

```
const options = {
        headers: { accept: "*/*", authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' }
      };
```

i tried removeing content-type,accept  as well , changng accept to applicant/pdf as well

even tried this

```
fs.writeFileSync("A.pdf", Buffer.from(response.data));
      fs.writeFileSync("B.pdf", Buffer.from(response.data, "binary"));
      fs.writeFileSync("C.pdf", Buffer.from(response.data, "utf-8"));
      fs.writeFileSync("D.pdf", response.data);
```

still same issue

Comment: what are the values in `options` for axios here: `axios.get(url, options);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` to axios options:

```
const response = await axios.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer', ...options});

// file is now a buffer
const file = { originalname: `${docName}.pdf`, buffer: response.data };
```

Comment: ```const options = {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        headers: { accept: "*/*", authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
      };``` like this?